# Срочно!! Проблемы с fetch_assoc() ПОМОГИТЕ!

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysqli

у меня возникла ошибка с fetch_assoc() код -

```
    function getImg($limit){
        $mysql = new mysqli('localhost','стер в целях безопасности', 'стер в целях безопасности','id15796999_news_bd');
        $result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $limit");
        return resultToArray($result);
        $mysql->close();
    }

    function resultTOArray($result){
        $mysql = new mysqli('localhost','стер в целях безопасности', 'стер в целях безопасности','id15796999_news_bd');
        $array = array();
        while (($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) != false) {
            $array[] = $row;
            
        }
    
        $mysql->close();
        return $array;
    }
```

сама ошибка выглядит так - Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in "тут путь к файлу с ошибкой" on line 101.
Я не могу найти ошибку помогите пж

Comment: @andreymal надо наверное сделать какой-то такой вопрос с ответом. а то предложенный не оч катит, птмчт даже ответ не выбран(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто: значит `$result` в методе `getImg` вернул `false`. Как следствие: у `false` нет метода `fetch_assoc`

Чтобы смотреть все изменения кода на каждом его этапе воспользуйтесь отладкой, пример описан в:
[Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482)